# Livewire 3 Package Development

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire

In the Livewire v2 there was a doc for [using Livewire within a package](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/package-dev). I could not find any related doc for v3. I tried the approach mentioned in the v2 doc but it does not work for v3.

I need to register livewire components from multiple custom paths/ namespaces. I want to register those manually.

Comment: It `doesn't work` is the equivalent of saying `we lost a satellite in space somewhere`.

Comment: @dbf, Thanks for your feedback. 
Let's focus on the issue I mentioned in the first two sentences, that I could not find any doc for packages as there is one for v2. Do you know the answer to this?

Comment: I'm all done now, hope it helps giving you a head first on where to look.

Comment: You can find the definite answer in **UPDATE v2**, short version, you're doing something wrong, probably not using the right namespace of your package when calling the Livewire components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### TLDR below.

Yea my comment was kinda lame. So no, I have never done this and have no experience what you can do about it. But there are so many packages using Livewire and registering components, so let's get to the bottom of this.

Let me take [laravel/jetstream](https://github.com/laravel/jetstream/) as an example, using [livewire 3.0](https://github.com/laravel/jetstream/blob/e74e1e1ad1ad98ce23f6c4e7f573352f681c365a/composer.json#L27) since its release from beta.

In the [JetstreamServiceProvider](https://github.com/laravel/jetstream/blob/e74e1e1ad1ad98ce23f6c4e7f573352f681c365a/src/JetstreamServiceProvider.php#L35) they are registering the livewire components quite differently, different from your example above. Using `register()` with the `callAfterResolving` callback instead of `boot()`.

```
public function register()
{
    $this->mergeConfigFrom(__DIR__.'/../config/jetstream.php', 'jetstream');

    $this->callAfterResolving(BladeCompiler::class, function () {
        if (config('jetstream.stack') === 'livewire' && class_exists(Livewire::class)) {
            Livewire::component('navigation-menu', NavigationMenu::class);
            // .. other Livewire components
        }
    });
}
```

Now if we go down the road and look how Livewire registers its components, it's quite obvious why they made this choice. It comes down to [these 3 lines](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/blob/97635fd0b4efcab5eeb50fc7d1ef27b9c97f2d9a/src/Mechanisms/ExtendBlade/ExtendBlade.php#L71).

```
app()->make('view.engine.resolver')->register('blade', function () {
  return new ExtendedCompilerEngine(app('blade.compiler'));
});
```

So to put it plainly, it would only make sense to make any component available in a package using the register method of the service provider, making sure the `BladeCompiler` is resolved. Why the [Livewire v2 documentation](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/package-dev) says something completely else (and Livewire v3 documentation not even mentioning it) is bogus to me, maybe they wrote it with the idea of some **standards** never implemented in Livewire, because Livewire has changed so much internally, I'll give all the blame to just a **blip** in documentation, which sadly happens.

This is how registering Livewire components in a service provider should look like.

```
namespace SomePackage;

use SomePackage\Livewire\SomeComponent;
use Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Livewire\Livewire;

class SomePackageServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register() {
        $this->callAfterResolving(BladeCompiler::class, function () {
            // 1. 
            // Check the existence of the Livewire class ..
            if(class_exists(Livewire::class)) {
                Livewire::component('some-component', SomeComponent::class);
            }

            // 2.
            // where 1. might be redundant because Livewire obviously set as a dependency in your composer.json, just skip Livewire existence check.
            Livewire::component('some-component', SomeComponent::class);

        });
    }

}
```

With or without the `if(class_exists(Livewire::class))`, the use of `use Livewire\Livewire` would already fatally crash if that particular class doesn't exist. So checking the existence of `class_exists(Livewire::class)` is likely to be stupid anyway.

### TLDR;

So this would be my final clean take on how to register Livewire components in a service provider:

```
namespace SomePackage;

use SomePackage\Livewire\SomeComponent;
use Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Livewire\Livewire;

class SomePackageServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function register() {
        // .. merge config, etc.
        $this->registerLivewireComponents();
    }

    /**
     * Register Livewire components
     */
    protected function registerLivewireComponents() {
         $this->callAfterResolving(BladeCompiler::class, function () 
            Livewire::component('some-component', SomeComponent::class);
         });

    }

}
```

Does this work? I have no idea, but I guess you'll tell me soon enough.

### UPDATE v1 spatie/laravel-dashboard

Though looking at the package of [spatie/laravel-dashboard](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-dashboard), they are registering the components in the [boot method of its service provider](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-dashboard/blob/211c6b8e2855fce222ddb0c7428520676a63a95f/src/DashboardServiceProvider.php#L13C2-L13C2).

```
class DashboardServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        // ... code skip
   
        $this
            ->registerPublishables()
            ->registerBladeComponents()
            ->registerLivewireComponents();        
    }  

    
    protected function registerLivewireComponents(): self
    {
        Livewire::component('dashboard-update-mode', UpdateModeComponent::class);

        return $this;
    }
}
```

Acting on the knowledge that the `register` method of a service provider is solely used to register (inject) services to a container (bootstrap) and the `boot` method to be used after all services have been bootstrapped (registered or injected), the boot method would be the logical place to register any Livewire components, so there must be a reason why Jetstream choose a different path. It's very interesting indeed ;)

So to come to terms, both methods explained in the answer **should** work.

### UPDATE v2 test

So I did some testing and could not find any problems running Livewire components in my test package.

This simple package exists out of a route called `test`, a view called `counter` and a Livewire component class called `Counter`.

The service provider set the view namespace and directory to be included and registers the component.

```
namespace TheCore\Test;

// .. skipping all the includes

class TestServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    public function boot() {
      // namespace called `test`!
      $this->loadViewsFrom(__DIR__.'/../resources/views', 'test');
    }

    public function register() {
       Livewire::component('counter', Counter::class);
    }

}
```

The route

```
Route::get('/test', function() {
    return Test::testView();
})->name('thecore-test')->middleware(['web']);
```

Where `Test::testView()` returns

```
public function testView() {
    // hence the namespace scope is set to 'test', 
    // else it will land in the app `views` directory 
    // and not in this package `views` directory
    return view('test::testing');
}
```

The [counter example](https://livewire.laravel.com/docs/quickstart) from Livewires quickstart page, where `render()` is only relevant:

```
public function render() {
    // hence the scoping of 'test' again. 
    return view('test::livewire.counter');
}
```

and the Livewire component being called in a blade

```
<livewire:counter />
```

Works as expected. I used all types of registration, in `boot()`, in `register()`, with and without the `callAfterResolving` callback, didn't change much.

So much for this satellite being found in space ;)

---

Comment: Thank you for spending a lot of time finding the solution and writing a long reply with multiple updates. I did not expect that. livewire component is working on v3. I am not sure what was the issue earlier but not I added `Livewire::component('some-component', SomeComponent::class);` in the boot method and it is available in the application.